# Prevent Duplicate Records When Adding Records in Datasheet View via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Disclaimer: I am very new to access

I have built a datasheet form in Access 2016 that displays data from multiple tables. The purpose is to have a visual representation of the data and data entry function similar to Excel so users will actually use the database. So far everything has gone well, except when adding new records it always adds a new record to each table even if it is a duplicate record. I understand that this is because of the way the form is designed. My question is: *can I get new records to avoid duplicate entries in my tables via VBA rather than changing the design on of the form?*

My current attempt thus far has been to:

***Edit*** *for clarity this an attempt to allow users to add records in a form that reference existing records in the Company Contact table. Indexing does prevent duplicates, but it also prevents adding child records to entries in Company Contact table.*

1) create an index in the table (Company Contact) where duplicates are occuring that is set to unique = true. Index is a composite of four fields

2) call a function on the BeforeUpdate event

3) function then takes the values of the new record's controls in the form that make up my index, searches the company contact table for duplicate record and changes the corresponding foreign key and key values of the new record

4) Unfortunately this does not work. I still get a message saying that I've violated the unique setting for the index.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function PreventDuplicate(index1 As String, index2 As String, index3 
As String, index4 As String) As Variant
Dim rstSource As Recordset, dbsSource As Database

'open company contact tbl & sets index
Set dbsSource = CurrentDb
Set rstSource = dbsSource.OpenRecordset("Company Contact", dbOpenTable)
rstSource.index = "CompanyIndex"

'sets current record to original
rstSource.Seek "=", index1, index2, index3, index4

'sets new record id to match and prevent duplicate
Forms!Master_Form![Main_Form]![Company Contact.ID] = rstSource!ID
Forms!Master_Form![Main_Form]![Contact Name.Company Contact FK] = rstSource!ID

End Function
```

Image of database relationship chart
[Database Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgrOU.jpg)

Comment: Should figure out why the compound index is not preventing duplicate entries because that should work. Why would form design negate this? Have you step debugged code? Are the variable values getting passed to the function?

Comment: As for the data structure, should not have ContactID as foreign key in both Tracking Number and Contact Name OR Tracking Number should not be foreign key in Contact Name. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: @June7 Stepped debugged, variables are getting passed correctly, watches on controls are indicating that they are changed as well. Double checked and it is finding the correct key value as well. The indexed  table is preventing duplicate entries, but the solution presented is attempting to allow new child records in the company contact table without forcing users to enter key values.

Comment: @June7 RE: Data structure, that's what I kinda figured. I haven't deleted the relationship up until now because it wasn't causing problems, but will delete.

Comment: I am confused. Company Contact is not a dependent child table.

Comment: @June7 child records to records in company contact. so records in contact name

Comment: Just not enough info about form design and what you are trying to do. And what the correct data structure should be. Are you using form/subform arrangement? Should not be any issue adding new Contact Name records.

Comment: Generally agree with June7 about more info being needed. 1a) Although the form shows data from multiple forms, it sounds like you have a single "datasheet" (with data from multiple tables on the same rows). Is that correct?  1b) Or, does the form have multiple subforms? (as June7 asked); 2) Share the form Record Source property (and subform Record Source properties?) (i.e. the queries on which the form is based).  (This would be more telling than all of the words shared.)